# R - Vegan package. metaMDS error

Tags: r, vegan

I would like to know why im getting this error running metaMDS:

> 'comm' has negative data: 'autotransform', 'noshare' and 'wascores' set to FALSE

I would like to do NMDS and dendogram graphs but can do so with the error above.

My data set is available for download if anyone wants to check [DATASET](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwRrvhEUMC1WTzRQeXB2cndvc0E). After importing the data, I transposed the column and rows. Afterwhich, I replaced the NA values with O before trying to run metaMDS.

```
    abundance <- read.table("1_abundance.txt", header = TRUE)        
    abundance[is.na(abundance)] <- 0
    abundance_trans <- t(abundance)
    metaMDS(abundance_trans, distance = "bray", k = 2, trymax = 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It is not an error message but information: `metaMDS` tells you that you have negative data entries, and it will not make some tricks that it defaults to do with non-negative data.
2. Second issue is that you ask for Bray-Curtis dissimilarities that are only applicable with non-negative data.

You have two alternatives: either take care of negative values, or use a dissimilarity measure than can handle them. If you think that you do not have negative data, you are wrong: computer knows. You may have an error when reading in your data, and you may have columns or rows that you should not have. Check your data.